# MVVM Android MediatorLiveData Nested Calls

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a list of Houses ids that I need to get. I get each house by doing an API call to fetch it. Then for each house, I need to make another API call to get its location. So the view will have a list of houses and I need to display the house's name (coming from first API call) and the house's location (coming from the second API call).

I am looking for the right way to implement this in a MVVM architecture. To get the list of houses, I am using using a `MediatorLiveData` like the following:

```
fun loadHouses(ids: List<Int>): LiveData<Resource<MutableList<House>>> {

        val liveDataMerger =  MediatorLiveData<Resource<MutableList<House>>>()

        ids.forEach { id ->
            liveDataMerger.addSource(loadHouse(id)) {
                if(it.data !=null) {
                    liveDataMerger.value?.data?.add(it.data)
                    liveDataMerger.postValue(liveDataMerger.value)
                }
            }
        }
        return liveDataMerger
    }
```

And to load one house:

```
fun loadHouse(id: String): LiveData<Resource<House>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundResource<House, House>() {
        override fun saveCallResult(item: House) {
            db.runInTransaction {
                dao.insertHouse(house = item)
            }
        }

        override fun shouldFetch(data: House?): Boolean {
            return data == null
        }

        override fun loadFromDb() = dao.loadHouse(id)

        override fun createCall() = starWarsService.getHouse(id)

    }.asLiveData()
}
```

So what is the best way to load each house's location and update the house's view to display the location?

Thanks!